# Post a picture to iCloud database using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to take a picture and upload the image into an iCloud database, however I keep getting the error: Type 'UIImage' does not conform to protocol 'CKRecordValue'

The code I am trying to use to upload the file is as follows:

```
data.setObject(picFile.image, forKey: "picture")
```

Is there something wrong with the line of code, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert it to a CKAsset.  I used the following code:

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picFile.image, 1)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0] as String
    let myFilePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("picture")
    imageData.writeToFile(myFilePath, atomically: true)
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePath)
    let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: url)
    data.setObject(asset, forKey: "picture"
```